# How do I extract photos from a .bak file created from a phone backup?

Tags: backup, restore

I want to extract some important photos from a `.bak` file.

I created a backup of my phone using Wondershare Dr.Fone software and now I have lost my phone, but luckily I have the backup on my laptop. But then I want to extract the photos from .bak file, but I cannot find a way.

I can open the .bak file using the application Wondershare Dr.Fone, but I cannot open the image, though I can see the image thumbnail. I can take a screenshot of the Photos but the thumbnail is too small.

It has no option to extract the images, can some please help me.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming, this site is for non-programming Android questions.

Comment: Backup software such as Wondershare Dr.Fone are closed-source and proprietary, so their file format and content may not be known by other than its developers. If their own app cannot show the full image, then there's little chance that it's even possible to do what you want.